# Map one enum to another enum

Tags: c++, enums

There is an existing enum

```
typedef enum
{
    myEnum_front = 11,
    myEnum_back = 19
} myEnumSides;
```

I want to create another enum `new_myEnumSides` and it's values should be mapped to the values of `myEnumSides`. Hence forth I would be using `new_myEnumSides` instead of `myEnumSides`.
Is the code below ok for this purpose?

```
typedef enum
{
    new_myEnum_front = myEnumSides::myEnum_front,
    new_myEnum_back = myEnumSides::myEnum_back
} new_myEnumSides;
```

Or is there a better way?

Comment: Can I ask why you're trying to do this?

Comment: The new enum would be used in a layer that would be exposed to the customer.

Comment: It looks OK, except that the `typedef` syntax is unnecessary: `enum myEnumSides { .... };`. Also, the `::` syntax only applies to C++11 class enums. C++03 enum values annoyingly live in the global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I can't possibly imagine *why* do you need to do it... If you don't need to *rename* the enum's values, you can just make another variable of the first one, without adding another enum (I believe this is not your case, but still have to point out this opportunity):

```
typedef enum
{
    myEnum_front = 11,
    myEnum_back = 19
} myEnumSides, new_myEnumSides;//<-- just add the new variable here
```

If you *do* want to rename it (which I believe, *is* your case), you should *not* use the `::` operator, but simply write:

```
typedef enum
{
    myEnum_front = 11,
    myEnum_back = 19
} myEnumSides;

typedef enum
{
    new_myEnum_front = myEnum_front,
    new_myEnum_back = myEnum_back
} new_myEnumSides;
```

The `::` operator should be used only if the enum is inside a class, structure or namespace, otherwise no `::` is needed.

Comment: The first example is misleading, because it doesn't make the values of one enum to the other. It creates two typedefs for the same nameless enum.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can imagine you wanting to do this is to *extend* an existing `enum` and create a new one with extra values.

As `enum` does not offer any form of inheritance, being compile time constants and really just integers, you *could* do something like this, although I don't particularly recommend it..

```
// internalEnums.h
myEnum_front = 11,
myEnum_back = 19

// customerEnums.h
someNewValue = 20,
someOtherNewValue = 21

// Wherever you want to define your enums
typedef enum
{
  #include "customerEnums.h"
} customerAccessible;

typedef enum
{
  #include "internalEnums.h"
  #include "customerEnums.h"
} internalUseOnly;

// Now there are two enumerations, sharing items.
customerAccessible::someNewValue // 11
customerAccessible::myEnum_front; // Doesn't exist
```

**EDIT** As per your comment, you could expose enumerations to the customer by keeping values in a header specifically for external use.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually the case that you don't want to expose details of third party libraries, but an enumeration that lies there might have the exact members you need.

In that case it's beneficial to create a mapping for the third party `enum`, so that even if the backend library changes, you can simply provide the enumerators yourself.

The most concise way to do this, is by creating an alias:

```cpp
using MyEnum = ThirdPartyEnum;
// {
//   enumerator1,
//   enumerator2
// }
```

This way, user code won't rely on third party internals,
you avoid doing conversions and even if the third party library is replaced, your users can keep using `MyEnum` by simply uncommenting the enumerator values (I like to keep them in comments, so users won't have to refer to third party libraries for documentation.